# Is there a size limit for PDB files in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, pdb-files

Is there a size limit for PDB files in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2008? Could exceeding this limit cause the debugger to hang?

Comment: How big is your `.pdb` file?  How much memory do you have?

Comment: It's 256MB and I have 3GB of RAM.

Comment: That's large but I've worked with larger ones without trouble.  There are lots of other reasons for debugger hangs.

Comment: My .pdb file has hit 1 GB and throws an error that causes the link step to fail.  It would appear that there IS a size limit (I'm using VS 2010) but I can't find it documented anywhere.  Any news on this?